# How to share image and description using social_share_button in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, socialshare

I want to share campaign name along with image and description  but it only share name

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(@campaign.project.project_name, :image => @campaign.campaign_image_url) %>
```

Is there any way to share image on social media?

Comment: Do you use any gem?

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get any errors?

Comment: gem 'social-share-button'

Comment: image not sharing only title sharing

Comment: If you have any example how to share image also

Comment: Have you glanced at this example? https://richonrails.com/articles/adding-social-sharing-buttons-to-your-rails-app

Comment: @AlexKojin......

Answer (score 2):

From the code snippets in the question I'm guessing you're using the [social-share-button](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button) gem.

Unfortunately, if an attribute you pass in to the `social_share_button_tag` is used depends on the platform you're trying to share on to, and each of them accept different params than the other. For example, Facebook doesn't allow you to specify images when you try to share that way. You can see the attributes that are passed into each of the platforms in the [social-share-button.coffee](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/social-share-button.coffee) file.

The best way to get the image to appear is to include meta tags for open graph which includes the title, description, image to use etc for that page. You can see all the relevant [Open Graph Markup here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup). If you render those tags in the `header` section of your page when its rendered, those images and other information will appear when you share the page. For example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<%= @campaign.project.project_name %>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<%= @campaign.project.description %>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= @campaign.campaign_image_url %>" />
```

Additionally, it'll appear even if the user shares the page using the URL straight, rather than going through that plugin. This has become pretty standard now and other platforms such as Slack etc will also use those tags to determine how to display a link on their platform.

Comment: It has to be in the `<head>` section of the rendered page @HaseebAhmad

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929653/placing-facebook-metatags-in-rails-application to check out one approach of adding meta tags to the header in rails

Comment: let me do like that

Comment: how i need to give links?

Comment: If you mean the link to be shared on to a social platform, you can give that along with the call to `social_share_button_tag` like so: `<%= social_share_button_tag(@post.title, :url => "http://myapp.com/foo/bar") %>`. When it's shared, the image, title, description etc will now be parsed by the social platform using the `og:xxxx` markup on the page pointed to by that url